# How to remove the variable names from the diagonal and put them on axes in R function scatterplotMatrix?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to reproduce a matrix plot on a book. Here is the plot on the book:
[image: desired plot]

Here are my codes:

```
y=read.table("T1-2.dat");
colnames(y) <- c("density","mach-dir","cross-dir");
library(car);
scatterplotMatrix(y,smooth=F, regLine=F, var.labels=colnames(y), diagonal=list(method="boxplot"));
```

And this is what it looks like right now:
[image: current plot].

How can I delete the names from the diagonal and put them on the side of the table just like the one on the book.

Thanks in advance.

Data:

```
> y
   density mach-dir cross-dir
1    0.801   121.41     70.42
2    0.824   127.70     72.47
3    0.841   129.20     78.20
4    0.816   131.80     74.89
5    0.840   135.10     71.21
6    0.842   131.50     78.39
7    0.820   126.70     69.02
8    0.802   115.10     73.10
9    0.828   130.80     79.28
10   0.819   124.60     76.48
11   0.826   118.31     70.25
12   0.802   114.20     72.88
13   0.810   120.30     68.23
14   0.802   115.70     68.12
15   0.832   117.51     71.62
16   0.796   109.81     53.10
17   0.759   109.10     50.85
18   0.770   115.10     51.68
19   0.759   118.31     50.60
20   0.772   112.60     53.51
21   0.806   116.20     56.53
22   0.803   118.00     70.70
23   0.845   131.00     74.35
24   0.822   125.70     68.29
25   0.971   126.10     72.10
26   0.816   125.80     70.64
27   0.836   125.50     76.33
28   0.815   127.80     76.75
29   0.822   130.50     80.33
30   0.822   127.90     75.68
31   0.843   123.90     78.54
32   0.824   124.10     71.91
33   0.788   120.80     68.22
34   0.782   107.40     54.42
35   0.795   120.70     70.41
36   0.805   121.91     73.68
37   0.836   122.31     74.93
38   0.788   110.60     53.52
39   0.772   103.51     48.93
40   0.776   110.71     53.67
41   0.758   113.80     52.42
```

And by the way, can we also display "Max, Med, Min" and the corresponding values on the diagonal as well? Thanks.